# IE11 is not responding due to a long running script error with Webpack + React + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internet-explorer-11, webpack-4

I am using `webpack 4.*` to bundle my `react 16.*` and `typescript 3.*` project! 
On our beloved internet explorer 11, I get: *not responding long running script error* and project never loads... both in local and test server (production mode)

I can not find out which side of the project is not supported by IE11 as it does not give me that much information and I also could not find anything similar in the internet... here is how it looks:

[image]

and my relevant setup are:

`webpack.base.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.tsx"),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build/dist"),
        publicPath: "public",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", ".sass"],
        alias: {
            // .... some internal aliases
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|png|webp|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|ogg|webm)$/i,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 1,
                    name: "[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: "single",
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    chunks: "initial",
                    name: "vendor",
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // ...
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.ejs",
            hash: true,
            // ... some internal values to be injected to the template, like gtm and etc
        }),
    ],
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    ...
}
```

`index.tsx`

```
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";
import "react-app-polyfill/stable";
import React from "react";
...
```

I think it can be more related to my code rather than the 3rd party libs... I do not have jQuery used and very same code works fine with [nwb](https://github.com/insin/nwb)! I just changed the bundler to webpack and updated npm packages to their recent versions

If further info was needed, I can share it via post updates

Comment: What is the size of the js files? try to use webpack-boundle-analyzer to detect which code can be split from the main js file

Comment: biggest one (`app`) is `1.30 MB` and all others are extracted out properly... I do use `webpack-boundle-analyzer`. same file works with old bundler in a larger size (around `2.0 MB`)

Comment: Whether this issue only occurs in IE 11 browser, please check whether it works well in other browser (such as Edge and Chrome)? Besides, can you post the webpack configuration file or create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It only happens on IE11! not on the others, not even early versions of Edge... I tested it on all of them, before posting this in here ;) updated the post with the base webpack config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a huge memory leak, somehow caused by [xregexp@4.3.0](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp)!

[image]

Since it was only used in two places, I got rid of the package and replaced it with built-in `RegExp` and all is fine now!

My initial mistake though was that I relied too much on `Network` tab! `Performance` section in the DevTool was way more efficient and helpful

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issue with XRegExp. Seems including that in the webpack bundle generates this memory link. In my case I include XRegExp in my index.html and it works...

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```